# Read eeprom have difference result in multiple times

Tags: eeprom

I'm trying read eeprom each time my device bootup, but something ware happened

Sometime data received not fully. Half are good, the rest are 0x00
I think when reading eeprom have drop voltage occured.

did you meet that before?

Thanks

Comment: You really, really need to give way more information. Which eeprom are you reading, how do you read the eeprom how big is de voltagedrop...

Comment: Hi Luc, my eeprom is P24C64F, it used in mobile device, I read eeprom by function supported by QC engine.
about voltage drop, I just suspect that, not yet actual measure